# CodeIgniter: Displaying data from two tables in one loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, templates

Let's say I have these two database tables:

```
blog     comments
-------  ----------
blog_id  comment_id
title    blog_id
content  comment
```

Now **I'd like to run through the 3 latest blog entries** and display the title, content and the number of comments made on that entry.

For that, I created a **Blog_model**:

```
function get_entries($n)
{
    if ($n < 1) {$n = 1;}

    $this->db->order_by("blog_id", "desc"); 
    $q = $this->db->get('blog', $n);

    if($q->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        foreach ($q->result() as $row) 
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

The model is loaded in the **controller** and passed on to the view:

```
$this->load->model('Blog_model');
$data['blog_rows'] = $this->Blog_model->get_entries(3);
$this->load->view('blog_view');
```

That gives me the three latest blog entries. I can now loop through the rows and display the content in the **view** like this:

```
<?php foreach ($blog_rows as $row): ?>

<h2><?=$row->title;?></h2>
<a href="#" class="comments">12></a>
<p><?=$row->content;?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So far so good. But now the tricky part:

**I'd like to display the number of comments associated with the displayed blog entry. How would I accomplish that, adhering to the CodeIgniter practices?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two proposals for the model method: the first does a query for each blod row, while the second does an unique query wich is faster. the second query is not tested.

**Model 1**

```
function get_entries($n)
{
    if ($n < 1) {$n = 1;}

    $this->db->order_by("blog_id", "desc"); 
    $q = $this->db->get('blog', $n);

    if($q->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        foreach ($q->result() as $row) 
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }

    foreach($data AS &$blog_e)
    {
       $q = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM comments WHERE blog_id = ?";
       $query = $this->db->query($q,array($blog_e->blog_id);
       $ncomments = $query->result_array();
       $blog_e->n_comments = $ncomments[0]['count'];
    }
}
```

**Model 2**

```
function get_entries($n)
{
    if ($n < 1) {$n = 1;}

    $q = "SELECT blog.blog_id,title,content,COUNT(comment_id) AS n_comments
          FROM blog JOIN comments ON blog.blog_id = comments.blog_id
          GROUP BY blog.blog_id,title,content
          ORDER BY blog.blog_id DESC
          LIMIT 0,?"

    $query = $this->db->query($q,array($n));

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        foreach ($q->result() as $row) 
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach ($blog_rows as $row): ?>

<h2><?=$row->title;?></h2>
<a href="#" class="comments"><?=$row->n_comments?>></a>
<p><?=$row->content;?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: It's good to seperate the comments from the blog model. So you would have a comment model that could do `$this->comments->blog_id(5)->return_number(10)->order_by('desc')->get()` which will get 10 comments from blog_id 5 oldest first. I like to use that fully chainable method because it cuts down on code size, is very simple and follows that same flow as the active record library. I'm not really a fan of all this `$blah->get(array('option1' => 'val1', 'option2' => 'val2'));` I find it irratating to write, and often you want to reuse those values in the model itself.

Comment: right, separate the models! this was just to show how to get the result, then the code could move to other files. BTW nice note